# Replace all value in JSON object array with key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Any one give suggestion . Without looping the json object . Need to replace the value by key.

Example json

```
var Arr = [{'name':'rajn',  'age':20 , 'status': 'offline'},
{'name':'jhon',  'age':30 , 'status': 'offline'},
{'name':'antoon',  'age':50 , 'status': 'offline'},
{'name':'knhon',  'age':40 , 'status': 'offline'}]'
```

Now here in one shot have to replace all status to online ..

Is that any pre defined javascript function we can use ?  How can we do this very simple steps . Normal iterate and change with key to value ..

Thank you

Comment: There's no such thing as "_JSON object array_". Also, there's no "one shot way" to do this, you will always need to iterate the array.

Comment: You can't do this without looping, you can use `Array.forEach()` but it uses loop underneath

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array.forEach()` to modify the `status` to `online`.

```js
var Arr = [{'name':'rajn', 'age':20 , 'status': 'offline'},{'name':'jhon', 'age':30 , 'status': 'offline'},{'name':'antoon', 'age':50 , 'status': 'offline'},{'name':'knhon', 'age':40 , 'status': 'offline'}];
Arr.forEach((item) => item.status = 'online');
console.log(Arr);
```

Comment: There is no point of `Array#map` here as the returned value is not assigned to anything, and the original array is already being mutated. `Array#forEach` should suffice, and is the right approach as well.

Comment: @31piy agree with it

Answer (score 0):

with spread operator es6, you can do this :

```
Arr.map(a => ({ ...a, status:"online"}))
```

Comment: Don't use `map` if you modify the same array, and not assign the new value. use `forEach`, it is faster.

Comment: i'm assigning the new value by using () as shorthand for return, but i didn't know forEach was faster, so thank's for the tip

Comment: Yes `forEach()` is more appropriate here @Pjetr agree with you